# Trying to get a random image from array, get all the same instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, dictionary

im trying to render a tilebased map on a canvas, with an array of 0s and 1s for the different images
Here is how I create the array:

```
var map = [];

function randomImageArray(){

var length = x * y;
var arrayLength = 0;
while(arrayLength < length){
    var randomImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 1;
    if(randomImg == 0){
        //mapArray.push('0');
        map.push(0);
        arrayLength += 1; 
    } else {
       // mapArray.push('1');
        map.push(1);
        arrayLength += 1;   
    }
}
```

}

and this is how I read it, and draw images from it

```
function drawBackground(){
alert(map.toString());
alert(map.length);
for(var tileX = 0; tileX < x; tileX ++) {
    for(var tileY = 0; tileY < y; tileY++) {
        for(var p = 0; p < map.length; p++){
            if(map[p] === 0){
                ctx.drawImage(image, tileX * tileSize,tileY * tileSize , tileSize, tileSize);
            } else if(map[p] === 1) { 
                ctx.drawImage(image2, tileX * tileSize,tileY * tileSize , tileSize, tileSize);   
            }
        }  
    }
  }
}
```

My alerts pop out a array filled with 1s and 0s, and a length of 300
but on my canvas i get either a map full of image1's or image2's

Comment: can you post a fiddle? I doubt the problem might be in the comparison of character map[p] with Integer 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logic problem in your `drawBackground()` function. You are looping through the whole `map` for every iteration of the outer loops, and the only image that gets displayed is the one indicated by the last value in `map`. Try this:

```
function drawBackground() {
    var tileX,
        tileY,
        imageIdx;

    for (tileX = 0; tileX < x; tileX ++) {
        for (tileY = 0; tileY < y; tileY++) {
            imageIdx = map[tileX * tileY];
            if (imageIdx === 0) {
                ctx.drawImage(image, tileX * tileSize,tileY * tileSize , tileSize, tileSize);
            } else if (imageIdx === 1) { 
                ctx.drawImage(image2, tileX * tileSize,tileY * tileSize , tileSize, tileSize);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can clean this up further by referencing your images from an array, and using the `map` values to index it:

```
var images = [image, image2];
function drawBackground() {
    var tileX,
        tileY;

    for (tileX = 0; tileX < x; tileX ++) {
        for (tileY = 0; tileY < y; tileY++) {
            ctx.drawImage(images[map[tileX * tileY]], 
                          tileX * tileSize,
                          tileY * tileSize, 
                          tileSize, 
                          tileSize);
        }
    }
}
```